# Fetching value from an php array and implode

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.5

```
Array
(
    [expert_skills] => ,1,2,3,7
    [inter_skills] => ,9,10,7,8,9
    [beginner_skills] => ,6,8
)
```

This is the array that I have and i want expert_skills , inter_skills, beginner_skills to be treated as an array which will have value as mentioned. Basically these are the ids that i have stored from another table.

But i am not able to fetch , i have searched and found that first i have to implode, explode these value(right hand side) and then put it in an array so every value will have unique location but how to implode exactly so i get my worked done

**Editing from here**

```
$sql_r = "select expert_skills, inter_skills, beginner_skills from user_personal_details WHERE upd_user_id = '". $_SESSION["user_id"] ."'";

$skills_render = connection()->query($sql_r);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($skills_render);
echo "</pre>";
```

here i fetched and did print_r jsut to see expected result

```
echo $skills_render['0']['expert_skills'];
```

and then just echoed expert_skills

```
$arr=explode(",",$skills_render['0']['expert_skills']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

and then foreach loop to fetch actual data from another database

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

  $sql45 = "select skill_name from user_skills WHERE id = '". $value ."'";

  $skills_render_value = connection()->query($sql45);

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($skills_render_value);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

I think I have got what i wanted but it looks messy

Comment: send the code you have tried out

Comment: what did your have tried ?

Comment: and what's your actual array looks like ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) :

```
$arr = array (
    'expert_skills' => ',1,2,3,7',
    'inter_skills' => ',9,10,7,8,9',
    'beginner_skills' => ',6,8'
);

$arr = array_map(function ($v) {
    return array_filter(explode(',', $v));
}, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

live view: https://3v4l.org/tDjbl

Comment: return with response if there are a problem